# iptable forward outbound traffic to LAN failed

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm trying to redirect outbound traffics to a specific ip address and port to another server in LAN.

I used the following command on my router:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1080 -d 130.83.xx.xx -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.34:1080
```

Which should redirect the traffic bound for `130.83.xx.xx:1080` to `192.168.1.34:1080`

However when I tried to use `nc` to connect to `130.83.xx.xx:1080`, nc will not make a successful connection.

I then dig a bit into the network traffic and realized nc got the response from `192.168.1.34` instead of `130.83.xx.xx`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/inHR7.png

I think this makes `nc` and potentially any other software that does this connection freak out and decides to RST it.

These are all run in VMs with bridge mode on network interface so the network traffic may look a bit weird. Packet No.1 is from the VM that runs `nc 130.83.xx.xx 1080` and I think packet No.2 is from the router that does the redirection.

Looks like the router is trying to `MASQURADE` source ip (192.168.1.17) but did not do the same for response, am I doing something wrong or did I missed some other iptable rules to make this work?

Comment: Add SNAT to outgoing interface

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
192.168.1.34 is responding directly to 192.168.1.17 without being processed by router kernel because they are in the same subnet.
So in order for this to work, I'll need to either create a vlan for each of them or physically separate them into different network.